# How to create a csv file without the table elements inserted in the file

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have this code that works perfectly fine but it prints out also the table elements. I don't know how to fix it. Thanks

```
<?php
    // output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=deferred_doc.csv');

    // create a file pointer connected to the output stream
    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    // output the column headings
    fputcsv($output, array('APP NUMBER', 'SPOC ASSIGNED', 'BORROWER NAME', 'APP_FINISH_DATE','DEVELOPER & PROJECT', 'COLLATERAL ADDRESS DETAILS' ,'ORIGINAL_DEADLINE', 'DEFERRED TYPE','DEFERRED_DOCUMENT','SPOC REMARKS', 'JUW-MA REMARKS', 'COSU REMARKS','FILE LOCATION','SMU NOTES','DATE COMPLETED','SUBMITTED/PENDING','ID'));

    // fetch the data
    mysql_connect('xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxx');
    mysql_select_db('export_workflow');
    $rows = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM COLLATERAL_MANAGEMENT');

    // loop over the rows, outputting them
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) fputcsv($output, $row);
    ?>
```

the csv prints out table elements like this [image]

Comment: just comment out this line `fputcsv($output, array('APP NUMBER', 'SPOC ASSIGNED', 'BORROWER NAME', 'APP_FINISH_DATE','DEVELOPER & PROJECT', 'COLLATERAL ADDRESS DETAILS' ,'ORIGINAL_DEADLINE', 'DEFERRED TYPE','DEFERRED_DOCUMENT','SPOC REMARKS', 'JUW-MA REMARKS', 'COSU REMARKS','FILE LOCATION','SMU NOTES','DATE COMPLETED','SUBMITTED/PENDING','ID'));` and no table headers will be output

Comment: @NikosM. Could've done `fputcsv($output,...,'ID'));` It takes less space. *Call it shorthand* ;-)

Comment: then you must have those in the db data (bad idea), but `strip_tags()` comes to mind

Comment: ahh i see now after new question edit.. yea probably `strip_tags` or similar is the way to go

Comment: I already fixed it, it uses a mysl code, I converted them to my_sqli

Answer (score 0):

I am doing a wrong code by using my_sql, should have used a my_sqli to fetch data from database